# Stateless EJB method return null in servlets

Tags: java, servlets, ejb

I have been testing my stateless ejb:

Java:

```
@Stateless
@Remote
public class PersonBean {
private String name;
private int reputation;

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

public int getReputation(){
    return reputation;
}

public void addReputation(){
    reputation++;
}


/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public PersonBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    reputation=1;
}

}
```

and the servlet:

```
    @EJB
PersonBean person;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    person.setName("Mahdi");
    String str=person.getName();
    person.addReputation();
    response.getWriter().write(person.getName()+"  
            with"+person.getReputation());

}
```

but when I call the servlet it returns: `null with 1`. It supposed to return `Mahdi with 1`.this happens in a single request. Why this happens?

Comment: Are both processes running in the same JVM?

Comment: This isn't the cause of your problem, but just FYI, in this instance you should probably be using a stateful bean, rather than stateless

Comment: @etherous stateful bean works fine. my question is why this should happen?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes both of them on the same JVM

Comment: I can't say for certain, but it may be that your EJB container is providing a different instance of PersonBean for each invocation, because it is stateless

Comment: What is unclear in "stateless". "stateless" means "which doesn't maintain conversational state". You shouldn't store state in a stateless service, obviously.

Comment: @JBNizet, the problem is, all of these happen in a single request

Comment: Each time you calla method on a stateless bean, you potentially use a different bean instance. Stateless beans don't have an HTTP request scope. They're not even aware of HTTP requests. They can't hold conversational state. Stateful beans are the EJBs that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand some key concepts about how stateless EJB works.

At some point, can exist several instances of `PersonBean` object located at the EJBContainer. 
This collection of instances is managed by the EJBContainer, 
which means that it can add/remove and choose which one will do the job.

```java
@EJB
PersonBean person;
```

If there are several instances, which one is injected by the previous code?

No one, actually `person` is a proxy to an object located in the EJB Container, 
that acts as an intermediary between your code and an ejb instance.

Every time you invoke a business method using this proxy, 
it sends a message to the EJBContainer component, which among other things, 
chooses from the list which instance will process the request.

Suppose there are three ejb instances:

```java
//the first one process this request
person.setName("Mahdi");
```

```java
//a second instance processes this other request, thus, null is returned.
String str=person.getName();
```

```java
//and a third one could process this; thus his reputation attribute will be 2
person.addReputation();
```

As you can see, the three operations (set, get, and addReputation) were resolved by different objects.